# Using Tableau to create a heatmap

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to Tableau (first day).
I have the data below where `D*` refers to one of three variables that are all correlated against eachother. There are 3 instances of each `D*` variable. When the same variables are against eachother, I have put an `NA`.

I want to make a heatmap from this data where the correalation values (coefficients) are converted to colors. Step-by-step, what can I do to reformat or otherwise the data to achieve this?

If my question isn't framed clearly enough please let me know in the comments.

```
    D1  D1  D1  D2  D2  D2  D3  D3  D3
D1          
D1  
D1  
D2  0.3 0.3 0.3 
D2  0.4 0.2 -0.2    
D2  0.1 0.3 0.4     
D3  0.6 0.6 0.6 0.2 0.2 0.2 
D3  0.6 0.8 0.9 0.4 0.2 -0.2    
D3  0.7 0.7 0.7 0   0.2 0.2
```

Comment: What data type is your correlation coefficient? I can see that it has both Text (NA) and some numbers. For the heat map to work in Tableau, the correlation coefficient needs to be quantitative. You may need to replace the NA with zero or leave it as null (blank).

Comment: Okay so NA's can be replaced with Null since it should be numeric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1: Create an Excel Spreadsheet with the table exactly as you provided above, but rename the different D* instances by adding a, b and c as required. Save the excel spreadsheet.

Step 2: Open Tableau and connect to the Excel file
[image]

Step 3: Select columns D1a to D3c
[image]

Step 4: Hover your mouse and click on the drop down arrow and select pivot
[image]

[image]

Step 5: Double click on F1, Pivot field names and Pivot field values and rename as appropriate. Note the slight variations in the names.
[image]

Step 6: Change the data type for correlation coefficients. Click on Abc and change as shown. Click on Sheet 1 when you are done.
[image]

Step 7: Right click on Correlation Coefficients and click Convert to measure.
[image]

Step 8: Drag the different D* fields to the row and column shelves exactly as shown. Drag Correlation Coefficients onto the Color Marks card.
[image]

Step 9: Click on “Abc” at the top as shown. Hover your mouse and click on the drop down arrow and Edit colors.
[image]

Step 10: Choose the options shown below. Feel free to use this format if you wish.
[image]

Step 11: Click on the end member green color and select the lighter green color as shown. Deselect “Use Full Color Range”. Click OK.
[image]
[image]

Step 12: Format the Correlation Coefficients as shown.
[image]
[image]

Step 13: You just built your first Tableau visualization! Well done.
[image]

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want. Great if you could let me know those steps. Thanks.

Comment: Since you are new to Tableau, I will need to give you a very detailed step by step instruction. I can do this tomorrow if you don't mind because it is late in the UK now.

Comment: OK that's fine. Look forward to see those

Comment: Kaleb, did this solution work for you? Accept the answer if it did.

Comment: @OkechukwuOssai If I could grant you bonus points beyond a simple upvote, I would. Your answer is impressive and I applaud the amount of time you put into this.

Comment: Sorry not at my desktop right now but I will try it out later tonight. It looks detailed. Thanks

Comment: This works great. THanks very much. On side note, is there any way to export to PDF or EPS without using Print (which doesn't give good layout options)

Comment: Awsheet, I spend my 3 days just looking for this, you save my life. Thank you very much