# How to create a correlation heat map in tableau?

Tags: python, tableau-api, heatmap, correlation

I have successfully created the correlation heat map in Jupiter notebook using python, but how do I replicate that in tableau for a presentation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Tableau to create a heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174030/using-tableau-to-create-a-heatmap)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.